# download large zip file in iphone upto 50 MB iphone

Tags: iphone, ios4, zip, download

I want to download a large zip file from server up to 50 mb in my iphone. so plz can any one suggest how will i download large zip file.

i have implement code for download a normal zip file but i want to download large files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no problem when downloading files of any size. Checkout `NSURLConnection`:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html

Answer (score 1):

directly taken from project:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    bytesCount = bytesCount + [data length];
    [receivedData appendData:data]; 

    //If the size is over 10MB, then write the current data object to a file and clear the data
    if(receivedData.length > MAX_DATA_LENGHT){
        [fileHandle truncateFileAtOffset:[fileHandle seekToEndOfFile]]; //setting aFileHandle to write at the end of the file

        [fileHandle writeData:receivedData]; //actually write the data

        [receivedData release];
        receivedData = nil;
        receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }

    [progressView setProgress:(float)bytesCount/sizeOfDownload];
}


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection {

    DEBUG(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[receivedData length]);

    //  Release and clean some ivars
    //
    [currentConnection release];
    currentConnection = nil;

    [fileHandle writeData:receivedData];
    [receivedData release];
    [fileHandle release];
..
```

and this is a part of the start download routine:

```
...
//  create a path in doc's folder and initialize the file handler
        NSString *temporaryZipPath = [self temporaryZipPathForResource];
        NSMutableData *fake = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
        BOOL result = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:temporaryZipPath
                                                              contents:fake 
                                                            attributes:nil];
        [fake release];

        if (!result) {
            [super showAlertWithErrorDescription:@"Error creating file"];
            return;
        }

        //
        fileHandle = [[NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:temporaryZipPath] retain];

        //
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[self audioPackageURL]
                                                 cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData 
                                             timeoutInterval:60.0f];

        currentConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

        receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];   
...
```

Hope it helps.